# Simple java swing program not running and showing exception

Tags: java, swing, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I tried to run this program:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
    public class HelloSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Swing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

and got this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2387)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:310)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2392)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:808)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1387)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1386)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:622)
    at com.masud.HelloSwing.main(HelloSwing.java:6)
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and openjdk16. It looks like a library file is missing.what will be my best course of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't rely on openjdk-16-headless.
If you are running on headless, the issue may be caused by missing libraries.

Headless excludes the window libraries to A, save resources and B because it runs in cli and probably without a monitor.

So why would headless have window libraries if there is cli only anyways.

To fix this issue, just open a terminal and enter

```
apt remove openjdk-16-headless -y

apt install openjdk-16 -y

OR

apt install default-jdk default-jre -y
```

Comment: It was headless. Thanks for your answer. I have just installed openjdk 16 using apt install openjdk-16 and the problem was gone away.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have openJDK 16 headless?  It probably is missing this library or your installation was corrupt and this library was not installed.

Find out which jdk has libawt_xawt and use that instead.

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search libawt_xawt
```

Comment: So you think it could be an installation of OpenJDK in the _headless_ variant (for a non-GUI server)?

Comment: Yes @JoopEggen or a corrupt installation, however most likley the headless jdk 16 does not have this lib

Comment: Yes, it is headless. I got it now. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/7064617/susan-mustafa